# Options for updating/migrating remote client standalone db schema during updates

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

**Scenario:**

I am currently working on a desktop-based application involving multiple independent production sites, each having its own server, database and local clients.

The software undergoes continuous automated updates, as part of these updates each production site's database (postgresql) will need to undergo schema migrations (while maintaining persistence/transformation on the existing data during the migration).

Accessing the client machines manually (e.g. SSH / Remote Desktop) to run scripts/perform the update is not an option. The client would need to be self-sufficient in checking, downloading and installing the updates.

**Problem:**

I have been looking around for a few months and have not yet suitable option apart from writing SQL scripts and using a separate service to run it one by one or using the updated app to run it.

**Question:**

What tools would you suggest would be suitable for this scenario to ease the migration process?

Comment: Schema migration on the server database or the client?  What will be the update process? How will you access the clients machine if ssh et all are not an option?

Comment: @MindaugasBernatavičius so the Schema migration will be on the server database of multiple remote standalone environments, which we cannot regularly access. These environments all act as independent production environments.

The strategy is that once a day/month the computers would poll a repository of some sort that we control to see if there has been an update. If there has been an update, it would download the update, install it and run the update all on its own. This means that all we would need to do is maintain the repository and the production sites are self-sustaining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a generally an accepted practice to run SQL scripts when doing database migrations. Tools like ActiveRecord (in the ruby world) provide an intermediate layer (a DSL), but are essentially wrappers around SQL.

There is a good reason for that - a migration is what is being done on the SQL server and the only strictly defined interface for manipulating tables in SQL servers is the PL/SQL language language flavor that the particular RDBMS server is using.

This means, that if SQL scripts are an acceptable option for migrations (acceptable in the sense that the team knows it, nobody objects to this, etc.) you should use them.

To make the task easier (the way ruby does it) you could take a look at: http://migrate4j.sourceforge.net/

They describe the tool as `The initial intent of migrate4j was to make a Java version of Ruby's db:migrate.` But this is not a fundamental requirement.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! I wasn't sure if that was best practice or not.